# Is there any ETL which can run BigQuery's cross region query

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, region

We have 2 datasets in our BigQuery, but thier regions is different.

The problem is we need to run query select from tables in both datasets, cross different regions.
We are considering about GCP service to solve this problem.
Which service can solve this problem?
Dataproc
Dataflow
Dataform
Data Fusion
Workflows
CloudComposer

We would appreciate if you could attach a reference link if possible.
Thank you.

We tried to make new dataset in BigQuery and copy tables from both dataset(diffrent region), but the new dataset is　required to add information of region too...so, the new dataset can only query select from one region...

Comment: Yes, any process can do it, it just comes down to how you do it. You can't move the data within BigQuery, but you can use an ETL tool to output it somewhere like Google Cloud Storage and then reimport it into a new region from there.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.